# figsize() function in pandas tutorial

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

in pandas tutorial, they use

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/v0.1/cookbook/Chapter%202%20-%20Selecting%20data%20&%20finding%20the%20most%20common%20complaint%20type.ipynb

```
figsize(15,5)
```

I assume this adjust the size of the figures. But where is this function imported from ?

I am just curious about this use, Normally, I use:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 16, 12
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That notebook was probably written for an IPython ran with the `--pylab` option, that imports `figsize` from [IPython.core.pylabtools](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.pylabtools.html).

It's not a good practice to use it, though, as it imports tons of stuff you don't necessarily use and also may clobber some other variables.

**Read more:**

- http://carreau.github.io/posts/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.ipynb.html